# regex infinite subdomains in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

I've following nginx config that matches main domain and redirects to new one, also matches 1 level down subdomain and redirects to new domain.

I'm missing case of subdomain of subdomain. e.g. `sub.sub.domain.com` or `sub.sub.sub.sub.domaon.com` or infinite levels really.

Any ideas how to safely regex this out?

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domain.de.com; 
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.domain\.de\.com$;
    return 301 $scheme://$subdomain.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Change `[^.]+` to `.+`. This will accept any pattern (including those containing a dot).

Comment: Why not just rewrite `.de` with an empty string. see http://serverfault.com/questions/489672/nginx-url-rewrite-with-string-substitution